# spring boot multiple data sources

Tags: spring-boot, datasource

I was trying to follow [this](http://xantorohara.blogspot.com.tr/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html) link to configure two databases in my application.

In the latest spring we don't have `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.TomcatDataSourceConfiguration` class.

What is the alternative for this to use.

I am using gradle for my spring boot application

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using "**org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource**", and then configure my data sources manually.

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
```

I set the fully qualified name, because you should return "javax.sql.DataSource" from whichever factory method you make.

Getting multiple data sources with spring-boot auto configuration is a pan, since the opinionated view is that you should just create a different service for each data source.

That is not always possible, so here's everything I do when I need multiple DataSources in a single application.

**Disable the auto configuration like so:**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class YourApp{}
```

**Create a configuration properties for your datasources:**

Properties file:

```
the-first.datasource.url=<insert value>
the-first.datasource.username=<insert value>
the-first.datasource.pw=<insert value>
the-first.datasource.min-idle=<insert value>
the-first.datasource.max-idle=<insert value>
the-first.datasource.max-active=<insert value>
the-first.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
# etc ...
the-second.datasource.url=<insert value>
the-second.datasource.username=<insert value>
the-second.datasource.pw=<insert value>
the-second.datasource.min-idle=<insert value>
the-second.datasource.max-idle=<insert value>
the-second.datasource.max-active=<insert value>
the-second.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

Configuration class:

```
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component("theFirstDataSourceProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties("the-first.datasource")
public class TheFirstDataSourceProperties{

    @NonNull
    private String password;

    @NonNull
    private String url;

    @NonNull
    private String username;

    private int minIdle;

    private int maxIdle;

    private int maxActive;

    @NonNull
    private String driverClassName;

    @NonNull
    private String validationQuery;
}
```

**Add a data source configuration class:**

Be sure and mark one of them as the "@Primary" to help with injection.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Copyright ${year}
 *
 * @author J. Keith Hoopes
 */
@Configuration
public class ExampleOfMultipleDataSourceConfiguration{

    @Bean(name = "theFirstDataSource")
    @Primary
    @Autowired
    public DataSource theFirstDataSource(
        TheFirstDataSourceProperties theFirstDataSourceProperties){

        //Fully qualified to not conflict with generic DataSource
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        // General
        dataSource.setName("theFirstDataSourceName");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(theFirstDataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());
        // etc ....

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "bDataSource")
    @Autowired
    public DataSource theSecondDataSource(
        TheSecondDataSourceProperties theSecondDataSourceProperties){

        //Fully qualified to not conflict with generic DataSource
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        // General
        dataSource.setName("theSecondDataSourceName");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(theSecondDataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());
        // etc ....

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**Inject your custom DataSources where needed using @Qualifier so you get the correct one:)**

```
@Qualifier("theFirstDataSource")
```

Profit? Yes.

**Oh, and here are the basic dependencies I use.**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-metadata</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
  <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It really helped me a lot to start with. I have one question. The second datasource created should be for saving spring data tables. How can I achieve this. I have a methid which returns a JobRepository, inside I use JobRepositoryFactoryBean to set the datasource and databasetype etc.

Comment: You will need to mark one of the datasources with "@Primary" and then use "@Qualifier" when injecting it where you need it. I suggest creating a separate post for data tables specifically so you can get more and better advice on how to handle that.

Comment: Also, if you have a sample/example project on github, I wouldn't mind taking a crack at it.

Comment: I am able to connect to different schema using the above. But when my JobRepositoryFactoryBean is executed, it picks the new schema, but saves all spring batch tables to my old schema

Comment: I'll really need to see an example project to help you more, which I think would be fun to do.

Comment: when can I attach the sample files

Comment: Create a project on github